# How to Select the entered values from the Multiselect listbox using vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010, listboxitem

I have a Textbox and a MultiSelect listbox with following values

[image]

When i enter the values in the text box and click on search it should select the particular values in the listbox. I'm Using the below code

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim str As String
Dim c As Collection
Dim strArray() As String
Dim intcnt As Integer

str = txtAnswer.Value
strArray = Split(str, ",")

For Each itm In strArray
lstAnswer.Selected (itm)= True
Next
End Sub
```

I want to get the below result

[image]

But It selects the index instead of values. for Example

[image]

How to select the values instead of index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim ItM As String
Dim c As Collection
Dim strArray() As String
Dim intcnt As Integer


strArray = Split(txtAnswer.Value, ",")

With lstAnswer
    For Each ItM In strArray
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .List(i) <> ItM Then
            Else
                .Selected(i) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next ItM
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code of yours selects by item, not value:

```
For Each itm In strArray 
    lstAnswer.Selected(itm) = True 
Next
```

To select by value, for each value loop the list values and, if found, mark the found item as selected.

Comment: Thank you for the response it would be helpful if you share the sample code

Comment: True, but I figured you could found out yourself having the method. But @R3uK served if for you.